# What should I change (Bisna-wise) in zend framework's application.ini when upgrading to Doctrine 2.2?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, upgrade, zfdoctrine

If I don't do anything, I get errors of the annotation driver.
I've read the upgrade doc, and know about the "use" statements to define the namespace of the annotations.

HOWEVER - I do not want to go over all my entities and add that to each annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the SimpleAnnotationReader instead of the AnnotationReader.

Comment: that is indeed something that is required to do. the problem is that Bisna had to be updated to support something else. That has happened in the past few days, so now everything is good!